# How can i get the google api key without using the command line keystore?

Tags: android, google-maps

let my problem is that i cant access the cmd(command line prompt) and i want to generate the SH1 certificate for google api key for mapview.So is there any way to get the api key without using the keystore? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function:

```
 private void getShaKey() {

 try {
 PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your_package_name",
 PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
 for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
 MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
 md.update(signature.toByteArray());
 Log.v(TAG, "KeyHash:" + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
 Base64.DEFAULT));
 }
 } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }

 }
```

Note that this is using the keystore too, but you won't nee cmd to get the API key